# How to answer install question in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried to install something using dockerfile.
But when I run the command, I have to answer the question like following:

**enter**

**6**

**72**

My dockfile is like following, but seems not working.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y expect
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common 
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
expect “Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it. ” { send “\n” }
RUN apt-get -y install php7.1 php7.1-fpm 
expect “Please select the geographic area in which you live. ” { send “6\n” }
expect “Please select the city or region corresponding to your time zone. ” { send “72\n” }
RUN -y apt-get install nginx
```

Anyone tell me how to answer install question in dockerfile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tested your Dockerfile and didn't have to answer any question, but if you want to auto answer when you run a command, you can use `yes` (for "y" and "n" responses) or `echo`.

Ex:

`yes | <YOUR COMMAND>`

`yes n | <YOUR COMMAND>` "n" response

`echo | <YOUR COMMAND>` echo generate a new line (enter)

`echo "some response" | <YOUR COMMAND>` response with "some response"

Comment: You're right. Seems like I get confused with the command yesterday.
I found that my problem is more like other issue, would you mind look into my new question here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272495/how-to-run-command-using-docker-compose

Comment: How to handle multiple prompts? for apache2 it is asking for region and timezone. How to handle this in dockerfile?

Comment: Missing multi responses required :( !!!

Comment: For exemple of _expect_ in a dockerfile  to choose european timezone : 
`RUN sudo 8 echo | apt-get install -yq expect`

Comment: unknown instruction: yes   unknown instruction: echo

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple questions to answer :

```
printf "answer1\nanswer2\nanswer3" | <your_script.sh>
```

The individual answers are separated by a `\n` character.