# Need to answer installation questions in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to answer plenty of questions during the installation process. How can I describe it in dockerfile?

*RUN ./Zoho_Analytics_64bit.bin -i console*

I need to answer

*Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Y
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter
Enter*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to answer install question in dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257866/how-to-answer-install-question-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Similar, but I need to know the syntax for many commands. Sorry if it is fresher question :)